# How to lose focus from Mui DesktopDatePicker field when clicking on another field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cherry-4cp1sx?file=/src/App.js

So I have two DesktopDatePickers from Material UI and I want that when I click anywhere on the field, it opens the Date Picker. However, when I click on one of the fields then click on the other one, the previous one is focused.

I tried using

```
        <DesktopDatePicker
          label="Created Date From"
          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
          value={dateCreated}
          open={openCreatedFrom}
          inputRef={createdFromRef}
          on
          clearable={true}
          onClose={() => {
            setOpenCreatedFrom(false);
          }}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setDateCreated(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              fullWidth
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenCreatedFrom(!openCreatedFrom);
                if (createdToRef && createdToRef.current !== null)
                  createdToRef.current.blur();
              }}
              size="small"
              error={false}
            />
          )}
        />
```

and

```
        <DesktopDatePicker
          label="Created Date From"
          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
          value={dateCreated}
          open={openCreatedFrom}
          inputRef={createdFromRef}
          on
          clearable={true}
          onClose={() => {
            setOpenCreatedFrom(false);
          }}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setDateCreated(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              fullWidth
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenCreatedFrom(!openCreatedFrom);
                if (createdFromRef && createdFromRef.current !== null)
                  createdFromRef.current.focus();
              }}
              size="small"
              error={false}
            />
          )}
        />
```

as well as calling the `focus()` and `blur()` functions in the '''onClose()``` function but none of them worked despite createdFromRef and createdToRef both referencing the fields.